# spring.liquibase.tag property not working

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

According to Spring Boot documentation, '**spring.liquibase.tag**' property is used to tag changes being applied:

*Tag name to use when applying database changes. Can also be used with "rollbackFile" to generate a rollback script for all existing changes associated with that tag.*

*from:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.liquibase.tag*

This property is available since Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE, and was added by this pull request]:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/19316

But after setting this property like this:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    tag: 1.0
```

no Tag is created on the **DATABASECHANGELOG** table.

My goal was to tag every database update with maven build version using ${project.version} in this property, to allow easier rollbacks if needed, without the need for creating tags manually.

Is this property even supported/used by Liquibase?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE and Liquibase 4.1.1.

Comment: I can confirm that this property is not doing what it's description says it does. My tag column for all entries is null when the property is set.

Comment: Looks like a bug, could you please log the issue in Liquibase's git repo: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues